# Javascript/jQuery - How come this endDrag event doesn't fire properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

In the following rich editor control (CLEditor, [available here](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/)), the drag gripper at the bottom of the box lets me drag downward and release okay, drag downward and upward and release okay, but dragging upwards causes it to never fire the endDrag event and I had to implement a timeout kludge. Do you know what I might be doing wrong in the jQuery/Javascript?

**Note: I created an example on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f3rRs/2/).**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var textarea, staticOffset;
var iLastMousePos = 0;
var iMin = 160;
var prevTimeout = null;

function startDrag(e) {
    console.log('startDrag() event fired');
    textarea = $(e.data.el);
    textarea.blur();
    iLastMousePos = mousePosition(e).y;
    staticOffset = textarea.height() - iLastMousePos;
    textarea.css('opacity', 0.25);
    $(document).mousemove(performDrag).mouseup(endDrag);
    return false;
}

function performDrag(e) {
    console.log('performDrag() event fired');
    var iThisMousePos = mousePosition(e).y;
    var iMousePos = staticOffset + iThisMousePos;

    // kludge start
    // Try implementing without this and the endDrag event won't fire
    // if you immediately start dragging upwards
    if (iLastMousePos >= (iThisMousePos)) {
        console.log('kludge implemented');
        iMousePos -= 60;
        if (iMousePos < iMin) {
            endDrag();
            return false;
        }
        if (!prevTimeout) {
            prevTimeout = setTimeout('endDrag();clearTimeout();',600);
        }
    }
    // end kludge

    iLastMousePos = iThisMousePos;
    iMousePos = Math.max(iMin, iMousePos);
    textarea.height(iMousePos + 'px');
    if (iMousePos < iMin) {
        endDrag();
    }
    return false;
}

function endDrag() {
    console.log('endDrag() event fired');
    prevTimeout = null;
    $(document).unbind('mousemove', performDrag).unbind('mouseup', endDrag);
    textarea = $('.cleditorMain:first'); // got a better selector?
    textarea.css('opacity', 1);
    textarea.focus();
    textarea = null;
    staticOffset = null;
    iLastMousePos = 0;
    var editor = $("#fldMessage").cleditor()[0];
    editor.refresh();
    if (!$.browser.msie) { // there's a quirk in IE
        editor.focus();
    }   
}

function mousePosition(e) {
    return { x: e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft, y: e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop };
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#fldMessage').cleditor({
        width:'100%',
        height:'100%',
        useCSS:true,
        styles:[["Paragraph", "<p>"], ["Header 1", "<h1>"], ["Header 2", "<h2>"],
               ["Header 3", "<h3>"],  ["Header 4","<h4>"],  ["Header 5","<h5>"],
               ["Header 6","<h6>"],  ["Code","<pre>"]],
        docCSSFile:"js/jquery.cleditor/jquery.cleditor.doc.css"
    }).focus(); 

    // BTW, if you have a more efficient selector than .cleditorMain:first, please let me know
    $('.cleditorMain:first').after('<div class="gripper" />');
    $('.cleditorMain:first').next('.gripper').css({
                'background':'transparent url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABsAAAAFCAMAAACD1meMAAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6QAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAAGUExURbu7u////3iwjPUAAAACdFJOU/8A5bcwSgAAABRJREFUeNpiYMADGHEDBhroAwgwAA9QADeT0qnSAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat scroll center 2px',
                'cursor':'s-resize',
                'height':'9px',
                'overflow':'hidden'
    }).bind("mousedown",{el: $('.cleditorMain:first')} , startDrag);

});
</script>

<fieldset style="min-height:160px">
    <textarea id="fldMessage" name="fldMessage" rows="4"></textarea>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this somewhere?  Also, performDrag(e)'s final if statement can never occur since you have assured that the iMousePos can never be BELOW iMin.

Comment: @Suroot I have just created a demonstration on jsFiddle. See the link now in the original question. What you will see is that you can click an drag the gripper downwards okay, you can click down and then up okay, but if you click and immediately drag up, it won't let you. Comment out the "kludge" block and it will still fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and it's the timing -- a browser quirk in all the browsers. I also used a revised example like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/bCBRW/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var textarea, staticOffset;
var iLastMousePos = 0;
var iMin = 160;

function startDrag(e) {
    textarea = $(e.data.el);
    textarea.blur();
    iLastMousePos = mousePosition(e).y;
    staticOffset = textarea.height() - iLastMousePos;
    $(document).mousemove(performDrag).mouseup(endDrag);
    return false;
}

function performDrag(e) {
    var iThisMousePos = mousePosition(e).y;
    var iMousePos = staticOffset + iThisMousePos;

    if (iLastMousePos >= (iThisMousePos)) {
        iMousePos -= 4;
    }

    iLastMousePos = iThisMousePos;
    iMousePos = Math.max(iMin, iMousePos);
    textarea.height(iMousePos + 'px');
    if (iMousePos < iMin) {
        endDrag();
    }
    return false;
}

function endDrag() {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove', performDrag).unbind('mouseup', endDrag);
    textarea = $('.cleditorMain:first');
    textarea.focus();
    textarea = null;
    staticOffset = null;
    iLastMousePos = 0;
    var editor = $("#fldMessage").cleditor()[0];
    editor.refresh();
    if (!$.browser.msie) {
        editor.focus();
    }
}

function mousePosition(e) {
    return {
        x: e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
        y: e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop
    };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fldMessage').cleditor({
        width: '99%',
        height: '100%',
        useCSS: true,
        styles: [["Paragraph", "<p>"], ["Header 1", "<h1>"], ["Header 2", "<h2>"],
                           ["Header 3", "<h3>"], ["Header 4", "<h4>"], ["Header 5", "<h5>"],
                           ["Header 6", "<h6>"], ["Code", "<pre>"]],
    }).focus();

    $('.cleditorMain:first').after('<div class="gripper" />');
    $('.cleditorMain:first').next('.gripper').css({
        'background': 'transparent url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABsAAAAFCAMAAACD1meMAAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6QAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAAGUExURbu7u////3iwjPUAAAACdFJOU/8A5bcwSgAAABRJREFUeNpiYMADGHEDBhroAwgwAA9QADeT0qnSAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat scroll center 2px',
        'cursor': 's-resize',
        'height': '9px',
        'overflow': 'hidden'
    }).bind("mousedown", {
        el: $('.cleditorMain:first')
    }, startDrag);
});​
```

So, anyway, it's the timing. I tried a completely separate rich editor control and found that the browser can't keep up (even Google Chrome) when you're resizing a richedit control (which basically uses an IFRAME). If you resize upwards fast enough, your mouse gets ahead too fast and the endDrag() never fires. It's just a browser quirk with drag events in the browser.

If you move the mouse more slowly, the problem goes away. **The problem is that the mousemove event gets lost once focus moves into the IFRAME.**

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but if the issue is that dragging upwards to make a size < 160 never actually causes an end-drag; the issue would be the if statement below.

```
iLastMousePos = iThisMousePos;
iMousePos = Math.max(iMin, iMousePos);
textarea.height(iMousePos + 'px');
if (iMousePos < iMin) {
    endDrag();
}
```

The Math.max has made it impossible for iMousePos to be < iMin. It could be <= but never <.

This actually is one issue; but is not the underlying issue that you're looking for.  The problem that I'm seeing appears to be related to masking of events.  This happens even if you drag downwards and then back up; you will loose the mousemove event.  Since it is possible to have an update where the mouse position changes more than just 1px, it is possible that the mousedown event is being lost as the mouse goes out of the .gripper area and into the textarea.  I'll look when I get some more time and will update; but there is a solution since it's been done here on SO if you edit a comment.  Most likely it'll be something like setting the mousemove event to the document globally and then having a global that states whether or not you're dragging.  Then mousedown/mouseup occurs and set the global dragging variable to have the move method work.

Comment: yes, that's the conclusion I came to as well. As soon as your mouse moves fast enough upwards to hover into the IFRAME, your event gets lost. I look forward to seeing what you come up with. That's why I'm not marking my answer (listed here) for now as the right answer. If one drags upwards slowly, however, the problem doesn't occur with the http://jsfiddle.net/bCBRW/ example.

Comment: I think that's the conclusion here, and perhaps I need to edit this entire post and reword the answer. The point is that if you build a gripper control beneath an IFRAME, all browsers cause the event to get lost once the upward mousemove moves fast enough that the event gets lost in the IFRAME.